# In sentences with infinitivals of purpose, where should adverbials of time be placed?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, time-words

When I use adverbs of time, and if the sentence gets long when I want to place it after the whole sentence like this:

> I sent a person to get myself a nice, delicious table of dinner today.

Or

> Janice and her friends went to the mall to flirt with the cute guys
>   who congregate at the food court yesterday.

Do "today" and "yesterday" modify only the infinitive phrases? Or do they modify the whole sentence?  And can someone please tell me how it is grammatically correct to put those adverbs  of time? Those sentences sound a little off to my ear while I am unable to explain why. It seems to me that I have to put those adverbial of times in front of the infinitive phrase like this:

> I sent a person today to get myself a nice, delicious table of dinner.

> Janice and her friends went to the mall yesterday to flirt with the cute guys who congregate at the food court.

Comment: The placement of adverbs in a sentence is often extremely flexible.  "Today I sent..."  "I sent a person today..."  or your version all work and are perfectly natural to a native speaker.  The first sentence has a broken pronoun.  It would be "... to get me...".  You would only say myself there if you had gotten your own meal.  I'm sure someone will explain the grammar of it, but it is a correct usage, both grammatically and idiomatically.

Comment: The second one too? Is it correct?

Comment: In the Janice sentence, the first version is a little clunky because of the distance between Janice's action and the adverb describing the time of that action, but it is still correct.  All four sentences are correct as far as their adverbs are concerned.  I would probably use either your second versions or simply start the sentences with Today and Yesterday, but the first two sentences are not wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is not wrong? It seems to me as if the today and yesterday are modifying only the infinitive phrases, not the whole sentence, therefore making it sound unnatural to me... Even though I now know it is grammatically correct to use those sentence.....

Comment: It's not related to your question, but *a nice delicious table of dinner* is glaringly unidiomatic.

Comment: What is an infinitival?  I have never heard of such a grammar term.

Comment: Regardless of whether they are technically correct, the first versions of each sentence sound wrong. The second version of "Janice & Co." sounds very natural. I think the first sentence would sound more natural with "today" as the first word: "Today I sent someone to get me a delicious dinner."

Answer (score 1):

*Yesterday* here modifies the main clause (or the verb in the main clause, *went*), so it can be put it any of these places:

> <sup>V</sup> Janice and her friends <sup>v</sup> went <sup>v</sup> to the mall <sup>V</sup> to flirt with the cute guys who congregate at the food court <sup>V</sup>.

With *yesterday* the positions to either side of *went*, marked with a lowercase <sup>v</sup>, are considerably less likely than the other three, but some other temporal locatives fit more comfortably in those two positions:

> Janice and her friends recently went to the mall ...
>   Janice and her friends went shortly after to the mall ...

WITH RESPECT TO THE EXAMPLE SENTENCE YOU ADDED:
(Some corrections: **1)** We would ordinarily say *someone* or *somebody* rather than *a person* here. **2)** You want *me* rather than *myself* - *myself* is used only as the object of actions performed by **I**, and *get* is performed by the person who was sent. **3)** A *table* is a piece of furniture and cannot be *delicious*, and *table of dinner* is not an English idiom. I suspect this is an idiom in your language meaning like a *meal*, so that's what I'll use below.)

Again, *today* modifies the main clause, headed by *sent*. Here are the positions where *today* may be put—again, the acceptable but unlikely positions are marked with a lowercase <sup>v</sup>:

> <sup>V</sup> I <sup>v</sup> sent somebody <sup>v</sup> to get me a nice meal <sup>V</sup>

Comment: Is the verb in the main clause "went"?

Comment: @helpmeplease Yes ... I will put that into the answer

Comment: Also, as I am not so great with grammar (I only know few terms, and that's it), is the main clause "Janice and her friends went to the mall", or does main clause also include "to flirt...court"? Again, I am sorry for my lack of understanding, but I do not quite get what you meant by "With yesterday the positions to either side of went are considerably less likely than the other three".

Comment: Do you mean that it is not recommended put yesterday before or after the "went"?  Also, what are those other three?

Comment: @helpmeplease 1) Yes. *to flirt with the cute guys* is subordinate to the main clause, naming the purpose, and *who congregate &c* is subordinate to the *flirt* clause, telling which cute guys you're talking about. 2) It is less likely that *yesterday* will be put in one of the two positions marked with lowercase 'v' and more likely that *yesterday* will be put in one of the three positions marked with uppercase 'V'.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You helped me more than you can possibly imagine :)

Comment: Oh, does adverb always modify main clause? When used at the end of the sentence?

Comment: @helpmeplease No; adverbials can modify other clauses/verbs as well. For instance: *Janice and her friends went to the mall yesterday to flirt with the cute guys who congregate at the food court after school.* Here *after school* is taken to modify *congregate &c*, because that's the closest verb and because present-tense-form *congregate* has a repetitive sense that works with *after school* in a way that *yesterday* does not. ... All this can get very complicated with complicated sentences.